# Pulling data through a serial port via .net

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, serial-port

We're using a load cell that pushes out the force of an object. Connected to it is a Smart sensor Indicator that deciphers the data the load cell is pushing through and shows it on a screen. We were receiving data and deciphering it fine from the Smart sensor to a .net application via a USB serial adapter.

Well the smart sensor went out and instead of buying another I'm trying to read directly from the load cell. I have the load cell and pc connected via a serial adapter as well. Well the issue is that once i open the serial port the *DataReceived* or *ErrorReceived* events are not firing.

Is it that I have to pull data from the load cell? If so, how can i do that? I know it's possible.

Comment: Does the load cell have a serial interface? usually they are just a 4 wire device that has an analog output measured in millivolts. What is the model number of the device?

Comment: @Mark The model number is CLC-100K

Comment: Looks like the load cell doesn't have a serial interface, just an electrical one. http://www.transducertechniques.com/clc-load-cell.aspx. You need a microproc with an A-to-D to feed you the data over serial. If you don't want to buy another Smart Sensor to do that, I might recommend http://www.ontrak.net/ADU100.htm

Comment: Well, what I was hoping to do is read directly from the load cell without anything else in between. The load cell has a serial cable, and I hoped I can connect directly to a serial port on the pc and receive the data.

Comment: Looking at the Data sheet, it has a standard load cell wiring schema. You will need a device to convert the signal to serial something like @antiduh mentions.

Comment: It may look like a serial Db9 connection but it is an analog one. It is very common to use Db9 connectors for load cells

Comment: You probably don't have to worry too much about destroying the load cell when you hooked it up to serial port :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To give this question an answer. The [specifications for the CLC-100k](http://www.transducertechniques.com/clc-load-cell.aspx) show it as being wired as:

From above link:

[image]

This is standard load cell wiring, with the West Coast color scheme. You will need some sort of converter to both power the load cell and interface the millivolt output to the serial connection. The only difference from normal load cells is the temperature compensation eeprom.